# Magento2.4.6 how to verify that varnish is already running

Tags: varnish, magento2.4.6

I installed Magento 2.4.6 and varnish 7.1 on ubuntu 22.04, and opened port 8080 on AWS EC2, but I didn't find varnish HTTP response headers on the Frontpage. But my website works fine. Do you know what I can do?  Below are some of my settings.

I followed the following tutorial to set it up.
https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-varnish-on-ubuntu-22-04/
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Varnish is successfully running on port `80` in your setup. Port `80` is the conventional HTTP port. However, requests sent to `http://127.0.0.1` are redirected to the HTTPS version of the website.

Based on the screenshots you shared, Apache is handling the TLS. Since the open source version of Varnish doesn't support TLS natively, I recommend that you install a TLS proxy in front of Varnish to handle the TLS termination.

This TLS proxy will then send plain HTTP requests to Varnish.

Hitch is an open source TLS proxy that is developed by the Varnish community. You could put that in front of Varnish to offload the TLS connection. See https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/terminate-tls-varnish-hitch/ for an in-depth installation & configuration guide.

Comment: I installed and configured hitch according to the official tutorial, but hitch cannot be started. I uploaded a screenshot of the configuration in a new reply below. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

1.SSH into your server where Magento is installed.

2.Run the following command to check if Varnish is running:

**sudo systemctl status varnish**

This command will show you the current status of Varnish. If it is running, the output will show something like:

● **varnish.service - Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-05-03 09:00:00 EDT; 10min ago**

If Varnish is not running, you will see a message indicating that it is inactive or not loaded.

3.Another way to verify if Varnish is running is to check the Varnish log file. The location of the Varnish log file may vary depending on your installation, but it is usually located at **/var/log/varnish/varnish.log.**

You can use the following command to check the log file:
**sudo tail -f /var/log/varnish/varnish.log**

This command will display the last few lines of the Varnish log file. If Varnish is running, you should see log entries indicating that requests are being processed.

If Varnish is not running, you can start it using the following command:

**sudo systemctl start varnish**

After starting Varnish, you can check its status again using the systemctl status command to ensure that it is running.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it's not a varnish installation configuration problem. This problem already has an exact fix provided by @ThijsFeryn.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a continuation of the previous question.

I installed and configured hitch according to the official tutorial,
https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/terminate-tls-varnish-hitch/

but hitch cannot be started. This is the first time I have installed and configured hitch, how do I fix this problem?
Below are some of my new configurations.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
ubuntu@ip-123-45-56-78:~$ journalctl -u hitch.service
May 04 14:27:54 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Hitch TLS unwrapping daemon being skipped.
May 04 14:54:54 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: Started Hitch TLS unwrapping daemon.
May 04 14:54:54 ip-123-45-56-78 hitch[174201]: Error in configuration file '', line 3: Invalid user 'hitch'.
May 04 14:54:54 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 04 14:54:54 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 04 14:54:54 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
May 04 14:54:54 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: Stopped Hitch TLS unwrapping daemon.
May 04 14:54:54 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: Started Hitch TLS unwrapping daemon.
May 04 14:54:54 ip-123-45-56-78 hitch[174205]: Error in configuration file '', line 3: Invalid user 'hitch'.
May 04 14:54:54 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 04 14:54:54 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 04 14:54:54 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
May 04 14:54:54 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: Stopped Hitch TLS unwrapping daemon.
May 04 14:54:54 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: Started Hitch TLS unwrapping daemon.
May 04 14:54:54 ip-123-45-56-78 hitch[174214]: Error in configuration file '', line 3: Invalid user 'hitch'.
May 04 14:54:54 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 04 14:54:54 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 04 14:54:54 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
May 04 14:54:54 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: Stopped Hitch TLS unwrapping daemon.
May 04 14:54:54 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: Started Hitch TLS unwrapping daemon.
May 04 14:54:54 ip-123-45-56-78 hitch[174217]: Error in configuration file '', line 3: Invalid user 'hitch'.
May 04 14:54:54 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 04 14:54:54 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 04 14:54:55 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
May 04 14:54:55 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: Stopped Hitch TLS unwrapping daemon.
May 04 14:54:55 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: Started Hitch TLS unwrapping daemon.
May 04 14:54:55 ip-123-45-56-78 hitch[174220]: Error in configuration file '', line 3: Invalid user 'hitch'.
May 04 14:54:55 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 04 14:54:55 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 04 14:54:55 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
May 04 14:54:55 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: Stopped Hitch TLS unwrapping daemon.
May 04 14:54:55 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 04 14:54:55 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 04 14:54:55 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: Failed to start Hitch TLS unwrapping daemon.
May 04 15:09:43 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: Started Hitch TLS unwrapping daemon.
May 04 15:09:43 ip-123-45-56-78 hitch[179666]: Error in configuration file '', line 3: Invalid user 'hitch'.
May 04 15:09:43 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 04 15:09:43 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 04 15:09:43 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
May 04 15:09:43 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: Stopped Hitch TLS unwrapping daemon.
May 04 15:09:43 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: Started Hitch TLS unwrapping daemon.
May 04 15:09:43 ip-123-45-56-78 hitch[179676]: Error in configuration file '', line 3: Invalid user 'hitch'.
May 04 15:09:43 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 04 15:09:43 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 04 15:09:44 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
May 04 15:09:44 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: Stopped Hitch TLS unwrapping daemon.
May 04 15:09:44 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: Started Hitch TLS unwrapping daemon.
May 04 15:09:44 ip-123-45-56-78 hitch[179680]: Error in configuration file '', line 3: Invalid user 'hitch'.
May 04 15:09:44 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 04 15:09:44 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 04 15:09:44 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
May 04 15:09:44 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: Stopped Hitch TLS unwrapping daemon.
May 04 15:09:44 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: Started Hitch TLS unwrapping daemon.
May 04 15:09:44 ip-123-45-56-78 hitch[179683]: Error in configuration file '', line 3: Invalid user 'hitch'.
May 04 15:09:44 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 04 15:09:44 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 04 15:09:44 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: hitch.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
May 04 15:09:44 ip-123-45-56-78 systemd[1]: Stopped Hitch TLS unwrapping daemon.
lines 1-58
```

Comment: Try running `journalctl -u hitch.service` to get detailed logging on why the Hitch systemd service didn't start. If that command doesn't get you the information you need, try running the Hitch command from the systemd unit file manually and add verbosity parameters. Once you figure out why Htich doesn't start, you can do something about it.

Comment: @ThijsFeryn
hitch[174201]: Error in configuration file '', line 3: Invalid user 'hitch'. [------]
hitch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Comment: Your print screen shows the user `_hitch`, the error message mentions the user `hitch`. Please check in `/etc/passwd` which user actually exists on the system and adjust the user in your config. If the user is set in your systemd config, there's no need to mention it in `hitch.conf` and vice versa.

Comment: I tried to modify the user of hitch.conf to the system administrator ubuntu and root, but it failed to start. https://prnt.sc/khnSZD1yUIud, https://prnt.sc/xtjwyJ6z28j-

Comment: Maybe remove the `user` & `group` directives from your `hitch.conf` since the `--user` and `--group` parameters are already set in your system unit file. The ones specified in your `hitch.conf` seemed to refer to an non-existent `hitch` user. By deleting the `hitch.conf` `user` and `group` entries, you might solve the issue.